# Windows Batch For/While Loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, recursion, while-loop

I know nothing about how to code windows batch files, so I was hoping the Stack Overflow community could help with a link to tutorials or tips on how to code a solution for the below problem.

I'd like to automate an existing batch file that converts SPS files to WAV. Below is the existing code. The goal would be for this batch script to run in a for or recursive loop that executes the "ealayer3.exe 259358.SPS -w" command in a folder, but for any file that ends in ".SPS". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
@echo off
echo Press Enter to start extract!
pause>nul

ealayer3.exe 259358.SPS -w

echo Extract Completed!
echo Press Enter To Exit
pause>nul
```

Comment: `FOR %%G IN (*.sps) do ealayer3.exe "%%~G" -w`

Comment: Somebody will soon ding you for not trying. Many of us could do this for you with a couple of lines, but that won't do you much good if you can't modify/maintain it to fit your needs. Almost certainly you would want to modify what someone posts. For example, you did not specify what order you want the  files to be processed (oldest first, newest first, alphabetically, etc). Take a look at the the Help for FOR and DIR. Then make an attempt to use a DIR command in a FOR loop.

Comment: Thanks @Squashman for the clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy:

```
@( SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_SrcFolder=C:\Path\To\Folder"
  SET "_Glob=*.SPS"
  SET "_CMD=C:\Path\To\ealayer3.exe"
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
  For /F "Tokens=*" %%_ in. ('
    DIR /B/A-D "%_SrcFolder%\%Glob%"
  ') DO (
    ECHO.Processing "%%_"
    "%_CMD%"  "%_SrcFolder%\%%_" -w
  )
GOTO :EOF
```